# How to change onPressed to one time function

Tags: flutter, dart

I am customizing flutter ecommerce mobile app from codecanyon.
How can I change the onPressed command to one time function that will work automatically for one time

```
onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

          await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Map(
                        latitude: latitude == null
                            ? position.latitude
                            : double.parse(latitude),
                        longitude: longitude == null
                            ? position.longitude
                            : double.parse(longitude),
                        from: getTranslated(context, 'ADDADDRESS'),
                      )));
          if (mounted) setState(() {});
          List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              double.parse(latitude), double.parse(longitude));

          state = placemark[0].administrativeArea;
          country = placemark[0].country;
          pincode = placemark[0].postalCode;
          //  address = placemark[0].name;
          if (mounted)
            setState(() {
              countryC.text = country;
              stateC.text = state;
              pincodeC.text = pincode;
              // addressC.text = address;
            });
        },
```

Comment: What does it mean 'will work automatically for one time' ? can you add full code, please?

Comment: are you trying to say it will be just one time clickable?

Comment: The code opens google mab by clicking on an icon to select a location.
instead of clicking on the icon, I want the mab to be opened automatically for one time

Comment: just make it a function and call inside initState.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
_openMap();
}
......
void _openMap() async {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
              desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

          await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Map(
                        latitude: latitude == null
                            ? position.latitude
                            : double.parse(latitude),
                        longitude: longitude == null
                            ? position.longitude
                            : double.parse(longitude),
                        from: getTranslated(context, 'ADDADDRESS'),
                      )));
          if (mounted) setState(() {});
          List<Placemark> placemark = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
              double.parse(latitude), double.parse(longitude));

          state = placemark[0].administrativeArea;
          country = placemark[0].country;
          pincode = placemark[0].postalCode;
          //  address = placemark[0].name;
          if (mounted)
            setState(() {
              countryC.text = country;
              stateC.text = state;
              pincodeC.text = pincode;
              // addressC.text = address;
            });
        }

.......
.....

onPressed:_openMap
```

Comment: If you don't understand the question, please ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: I tried to do it this way but I faced this error

Error: Place positional arguments before named arguments.
Try moving the positional argument before the named arguments, or add a name to the argument.
    void _openMap() async {